# MySQL Performance DATE_FORMAT() vs YEAR() AND MONTH()

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Which is better for performance when looking for timestamps in current month and year?

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = YEAR(mytable.timestamp)
  AND MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = MONTH(mytable.timestamp)
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(mytable.timestamp,'%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Why dont you try it?  I would say they should have similiar performance because cant use index. (they arent sargeable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For better perfomance and able to use index in `mytable.timestamp`, truncate the current date to month.

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%Y-%m-01')
```

This create a constant value and you can index search for it.

And then you can get all the record from this month

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE mytable.timestamp >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%Y-%m-01')
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting answer. I think this is the way to go

Comment: @user3790083 yes this is good; conversely, it is almost never a good idea to use columns as arguments to functions in the `WHERE` clause, because this defeats indexes and often forces the server to evaluate the function for Every. Single. Row. This solution avoids that by comparing to something resolvable to a constant expression, since the `NOW()`-like functions freeze their value when a query starts and hold it until the query is done, within the running query.  If you ran this query right before midnight on the last day of the year, it would not suddenly be wrong, halfway through.